# Error Opening WMS Maplayer: URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 10060]

Tags: wms, web-mapping, mapserver, connection

I receive the error:

```
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond>
```

when attempting to open a webpage containing a WMS map. This is part of a mapping system we run on client machines. I have the system running on multiple clients and have not encountered this error before.

It errors at:

```
mapServerUrl = settings.MAPSERVERABSOLUTEURL+"?map="+map_file wms = WebMapService(mapServerUrl, version='1.1.1')
```

It fails a urllib do_open() command, which is not in my code. I tested the map server url manually and received a non-response.

It seems to time-out loading the page. I posted this to the general stack overflow forum, but thought it might be an issue with Mapserver.

The solution from Microsoft for this error is: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/811087 . This does not work because to the best of my knowledge they are not operating a proxy server. I also tried turning off firewalls, etc because this seemed to work for others having similar issues. Any suggestions for trouble shooting would be helpful.

It has been suggested to increase the timeout, but the server already fails before the default 60 seconds (after about 10 seconds) and I have not experienced this issue on other installations.

Comment: I believe that error happens before MapServer is involved. Are you sure that those clients can connect the server at all?

Comment: They are able to connect to the main pages. We have a second window that opens with an interactive view of the maps generated, which does not load. I found this page: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/811087. I am not sure if this is the issue though.